# How would I find the Binormal vector?

Tags: plotting, vector

How would I find the Binormal vector if r[t_]:={sin(7t),t^4,cos(7t)} in Mathematica?

This is the Mathematica code I have:

```
    r[t_] := {Sin[7 t], t^4, Cos[7 t]};
    circle := 
    ParametricPlot3D[r[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi/7}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, 
    Black}]
    utvec[t_] := {r'[t]/sqrt[r'[t].r'[t]]}
    utvec[0.4]
    (r'[0.4])*t + r[0.4]
    Show[circle, 
    ParametricPlot3D[(r'[0.4])*t + r[0.4], {t, 0, 2 Pi/7}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}]]
    nvec[t_] := {r''[t]/sqrt[r''[t].r''[t]]}
    nvec[0.4]
    (r''[0.4])*t + r[0.4]
    ubnvec[t_] := Cross[utvec[t], nvec[t]]
```

Also, how can I graph something that looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE. To get started:1) take [the introductory tour now](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour),2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up [by clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge,3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work),4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code. Please see `FrenetSerretSystem`

Comment: Please, also, fix your sytnax properly. It should be `r[t_] := {Sin[7 t], t^4, Cos[7 t]}`

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

```
r[t_] := {Sin[7 t], t^4, Cos[7 t]}
```

Now, we can implement directly the definition of the binormal vector

```
FullSimplify[Cross[r'[t], r''[t]]/Norm[Cross[r'[t], r''[t]]]]
```

which gives

> `{(4 t^2 (-7 t Cos[7 t] + 3 Sin[7 t]))/Sqrt[ 2401 + 16 Abs[t^2 (-7 t Cos[7 t] + 3 Sin[7 t])]^2 +  16 Abs[t^2 (3 Cos[7 t] + 7 t Sin[7 t])]^2], 49/Sqrt[ 2401 + 16 Abs[t^2 (-7 t Cos[7 t] + 3 Sin[7 t])]^2 +  16 Abs[t^2 (3 Cos[7 t] + 7 t Sin[7 t])]^2], ( 4 t^2 (3 Cos[7 t] + 7 t Sin[7 t]))/Sqrt[ 2401 + 16 Abs[t^2 (-7 t Cos[7 t] + 3 Sin[7 t])]^2 +  16 Abs[t^2 (3 Cos[7 t] + 7 t Sin[7 t])]^2]}`

In case that `t` is real, we can inform `Mathematica` about that fact as follows:

```
FullSimplify[Cross[r'[t], r''[t]]/Norm[Cross[r'[t], r''[t]]], 
 t ∈ Reals]
```

which results in

> 

```
{(4 t^2 (-7 t Cos[7 t] + 3 Sin[7 t]))/Sqrt[
 2401 + 144 t^4 + 784 t^6], 49/Sqrt[2401 + 144 t^4 + 784 t^6], (
 4 t^2 (3 Cos[7 t] + 7 t Sin[7 t]))/Sqrt[2401 + 144 t^4 + 784 t^6]}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
r[t_] = {Sin[7 t], t^4, Cos[7 t]};
{tangent, normal, binormal} = FrenetSerretSystem[r[t], t][[2]];
t = 1;
Show[ParametricPlot3D[r[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi/5}, PlotStyle -> Yellow], 
 Graphics3D[{AbsoluteThickness[5], White, 
   Arrow[{r[t], r[t] + tangent}], Blue, Arrow[{r[t], r[t] + normal}], 
   Red, Arrow[{r[t], r[t] + binormal}]}], Background -> Cyan, 
 PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 ViewPoint -> {1.20, 2.86, -1.31}, 
 ViewVertical -> {0.25, 0.96, -0.04}]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) nice use of the `FrenetSerretSystem` for these purposes!

Comment: (+1) Thank you :)